# Could Belief in Little Fears: Nightmare Edition cause the dark side of the moon to really be dark?

Tags: adventure-writing, little-fears

I'm writing an episode which involves a plot by the monster Vanish involving possessing the dark side of the moon (if you don't know, his power is to possess shadows). I was going with the fact that the term "the dark side of the moon" would cause enough children to believe that it really was dark for Belief to make it so, but I'm not entirely sure that Belief works that way. Does it?

Comment: Could you either add a system or make this system agnostic?

Comment: Added a system tag, though it's the only game with this tag currently. Feel free to untag it if the tag is wrong.

Comment: I'm confused – there seems to be an unstated assumption here that the dark side of the moon is not actually dark. But the dark side of the moon _is_ in shadow from the sun. Perhaps you're thinking of the _far_ side of the moon (which is not the same thing)?

Comment: @Bradd, "dark side of the moon" can have the same meaning as "far side of the moon". I believe it was used in this fashion during the Apollo program. In this case, it's "dark" because it can't be seen from Earth and is thus mysterious.

Answer (score 7):

It's been a long while since I played Little Fears and I never did GM it, but from what I remember Belief was a child's main defensive thing.  It also had it's negative side such as holding your breath when riding through a tunnel, or lifting your feet when riding over rail road tracks, or not stepping on cracks in the sidewalk.  All of which have some form of negative consequence which can have a regional component in some cases.

Judging by your wording of the question, "would cause enough children to believe that", it sounds you may want to impose a threshold of some kind on the plot.  From what I remember, you don't need to go that far.  Only one believer would be needed to make it happen.  But children that didn't believe, say because they never heard of the possibility, would not be subject to the effect.  The beautiful thing is that once a group of children hear about something, some of them will believe.  A real life example of that being a young sibling of my friend believed I had a battery in my big toe.  Why?  I said I did.  It was that simple.  In the same way, agents of Closetland could spread negative believes that serve one of the seven kings or whatever master the agent follows.  If you get to them young enough they will believe some really wild stories.

Have fun with Little Fears, I may have to go looking for it again.

Comment: I meant as in with the same effect that causes monsters like Stranger Danger and Sewer Thing to exist- an image or concept that enough people, not necessarily the party, believe in that it becomes a thing. Also, it seems your answer may be a bit off because you've only read the original- there are a lot of changes in the modern Nightmare Edition, the removal of the seven kings being the one tipping me off. But still, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @NessGardna Ah OK, I'll have to look at the newer stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it totally can! Believe is the immense magic force, which spawned the whole dimension called Closetland into existence!
So the far side of the moon could really be a dark place, where the sun never reached - although adults would not see it as such, or would find a scientific explanation!